# How to install *.app file to real device by script?

Tags: ios, simulator, xcrun, simctl

1. Get device list

`xcrun xctrace list devices`

=>    'Simson’s iPhone 11 (14.4.2) (00008030-00122CD62291802E)'

2. Install app file

`xcrun simctl install 00008030-00122CD62291802E app/ios/test.app`

Then I get error:

```
  stderr: 'Invalid device: 00008020-00151D0101A1002E'
  code: 148
```

FYI,

Other simulator device

```
iPhone 11 (14.2) (8C7A8554-23D2-4E89-BC42-99A87D550067)
iPhone 11 Pro (14.2) (BE017979-0F60-4C0E-A203-B94951969071)
```

If I replace `00008020-00151D0101A1002E` by `8C7A8554-23D2-4E89-BC42-99A87D550067` or `BE017979-0F60-4C0E-A203-B94951969071` will work.

Please help.

Comment: Did you built the ipa for a device, or for the simulator?

Comment: Yup i built, the file is available

Comment: I think issue here is uuid of device. The format doesn't like simulator uuid

Comment: I'm having the same problem, apparently this command 'simctl' simulators only